# Aeson parsing dynamic objects

Tags: haskell, aeson

I need to parse json API responses which don't have strict structure:

```
{
 response: { /* any object here */ }
}
```

How is it possible to write `parseResponse` which will leave ability to parse (or choose a Parser for it) for later use?

My last try is below. I don't like it because it doesn't allow to choose response type as Aeson's `decode` does.

```
data APIResponse =
  APIResponse { response :: Value } deriving (Show,Generic)

instance FromJSON APIResponse

parseResponse :: BC.ByteString -> Either String Value
parseResponse resp =
  case eitherDecode . BLC.fromStrict $ resp of
    Right x -> Right $ response x
    Left msg -> Left msg
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like to think of Aeson as happening in two distinct steps, the parsing from `ByteString -> Value` and the mapping from `FromJSON a => Value -> a`. If you don't immediately know what the correct mapping is you can simply parse to a `Value` as you've done. Later at runtime when you decide the proper mapping you can do that later.

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as Hm

decodeResponse :: ByteString -> Either String Value
decodeResponse bs = do
  val <- eitherDecode bs
  case val of
    Object o -> case Hm.lookup "response" o of
                  Nothing   -> fail "Invalid structure, missing 'response' key"
                  Just resp -> return resp
    _ -> fail "Invalid structure, expected an object"
```

To perform a mapping without a parse, to convert a `Value` to a `FromJSON a => a`, you use the `parse`/`parseEither`/`parseMaybe` family and run the parser generated by `parseJSON`

```
mapValue :: FromJSON a => Value -> Either String a
mapValue = parseString parseJSON
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Could you please point me which category Data.Aeson's docs should I look to find a way for converting Value to Array [Value]?

Comment: Take a look at the `parse`/`parseMaybe`/`parseEither` family. The specific section would be [Decoding a mixed-type object](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson.html). You could also just pattern match on `Value` and use `vector` operations to unpack the `Array`.